# How do I refresh jsf page when downloading a file?

Tags: ajax, jsf, download

I want to refresh jsf page(or using ajax to update part of page), when downloading a file. But there is a conflict between them now. html code like that:

```
<h:commandButton id="download-button" name="download-button"
action="#{myController.download}" value="download"></h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Do you want to refresh before download starts, or after download finishes?

Comment: Before downloads starts. I will appreciate it, if you have good solution.

Comment: But there are some problems, I want to use ajax update current page, but not open a new page.

Comment: Question is perhaps different, but answer is the same: conditionally render some JavaScript which in turn triggers download.

Comment: How to render the JavaScript after clicking commandButton? Current method is invalid. I have added the following code:
`<h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty myController.msg}">
 alert(123);
</h:outputScript>`